# How to make a loop which display the output for my program automatically

Tags: matlab, octave

In my program , suppose I fix no. of users `N=6` .
Threshold value of SIR `SIRo=6`; Output generated is `SIRmean=10` (suppose).

I want to make a loop so that

```
if SIRmean < SIRo

   disp N=6

else

  decrease the counter till SIRmean> SIRo
   and display the value of N for which this condition holds true.

end
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, can you explain it please?

Comment: Actually i want to make a loop which should calculate the no. of users satisfying the condition. I have fixed the no. of users arbitrary to some value N=6 and also fixed the threshold value to 6. Now I want to compare my output value with threshold and if my output is less than threshold then result should display N=6 otherwise the loop should decrease the counter of no. of users and then check whether the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple for loop with downcounter and break on condition:

```
N=6;
for k=N:-1:0
   SIRmean = calc_SIR_mean(N);
   if SIRmean < SIRo
      disp(['N=' k])
      break;
   end
end
```

Function `calc_SIR_mean` should return mean value based on number of users (it is not clear from your question how you receive this value).